# Wrap texture evenly around mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates, height-map

I am trying to wrap this brick texture evenly around this controller 3d model, I can get it evenly around some parts but the handles are causing me problems. [image: Messed Up Handle]

Answer (score 1):

Imaging you are wrapping this object with paper with this print; How would you like the pattern to be cut? There is no magic button for this. You need to UV unwrap it carefully and make decisions about how you want the pattern to be distorted.

Comment: I dont want it to be wrapped a certain way, I just want it to have an even texture across the entire surface

Comment: "Even across the entire surface" is a very certain way. Not only that... it's impossible.

Comment: how can I get close? I want it to be like wallpaper not like spandex

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, what I did was make an image of one brick in photoshop and then put it on as a generated normal map.